# Convert array of [char] to String and then add to ListView in Android?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am new to Java and Android programming. For an Android project, I need to transform an array of two chars in a String and then add the result in a ListView.

The two chars come from a for-loop that represents a pair of char from "AA" to "ZZ". I use the for-loop to generate an ASCII code of alphabetic letter.

```
btn_MANAGER_SlaveRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                char[] AdrBuffer = null;
                final String txt_Adr = "ZZ";

                for (byte MSB_Adr = 65; MSB_Adr <= 90; MSB_Adr++) {
                    for (byte LSB_Adr = 65; LSB_Adr <= 90; LSB_Adr++) {
                        AdrBuffer[0] = (char)MSB_Adr;
                        AdrBuffer[1] = (char)LSB_Adr;
                        txt_Adr.copyValueOf(AdrBuffer);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                adapter_lst_MANAGER_SlaveActive.add(txt_Adr);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }   
            }
        }).start();
    }
});
```

When I click on the button, the application stops and closes.

Can you help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: copyValueOf does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append((char)MSB_Adr);
builder.append((char)LSB_Adr);

String txt_Adr = builder.toString();
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks Gopi ! It Work correctly ! Thanks very uch for your help, and sorry for my poor question :-/

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to your code and eventually, it worked! You included the while loop in a separate thread, that was fine but maybe that .copyValueOf() method was causing some problems. Below I'm providing a refined version of your code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {


private ListView lv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();





    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, R.id.name);
        int j=65;
        for(int i=0;i<=25;i++) {


            char one=(char) j;

           adapter.add(""+one+one);

            j++;

        }
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
  }
```

Please let me know if this works and if you have any problem understanding the code, let me know. cheers!

Comment: Thanks Sushant for your answer :-)